# Распарсить html страницу с помощью пайтона

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, парсер

Есть страница https://www.leovegas.com/en-in/popular, необходимо вытащить оттуда все названия игр. Владею немного пайтоном( Анаконда).Нашла на просторах сети и адаптировала под себя. но не работает:

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as input_file:
        text = input_file.read()
    return text



def parse_user_datafile_bs(filename):
    results = []
    text = read_file(filename)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    film_list = soup.find('div', {'class': '_1PGOG'})
    items = film_list.find_all('div', {'class': ['_1PGOG']})
    for item in items:
        # getting movie_id
        movie_link = item.find('a', {'class': '_3efGW'}).find('a').get('href')
        movie_desc = item.find('a', {'class': '_3efGW'}).find('a').text
        #movie_id = re.findall('\d+', movie_link)[0]

        # getting english name
#         name_eng = item.find('div', {'class': 'nameEng'}).text

#         #getting watch time
#         watch_datetime = item.find('div', {'class': 'date'}).text
#         date_watched, time_watched = re.match('(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}), (\d{2}:\d{2})', watch_datetime).groups()

#         # getting user rating
#         user_rating = item.find('div', {'class': 'vote'}).text
#         if user_rating:
#             user_rating = int(user_rating)

        results.append({
                'game': movie_id

            })
    return results
parse_user_datafile_bs('LeoVegas.html')
```

Comment: А какие у вас возникли проблемы? Пока вопрос выглядит как запрос на сайте фриланса :) обычно парсят через связку requests+bs4 или selenium. Для парсинга лучше открыть инспектор (F12) и там смотреть структуру страницы (чтобы знать что можно вытащить и как), смотреть на вкладку Сети (если для получения данных нужно какие-то запрос отправить) и смотреть исходный код страницы. Посмотрел на ту ссылку и данные по играм можно попробовать вытащить из тегов html либо из куска js кода (см. на `window.__INITIAL_STATE` в исходном коде)

Comment: @gil9red Вот, то что я адаптировала под себя, но не работает - поэтому и спрашиваю у ребят, может кто делал подобное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот сайт заблокирован моим провайдером, возиться с прокси для `requests` не стал, да и ваш пример работает с файлом, поэтому, думаю ничего страшного нет.

- Скачал из браузера страницу
- Делаю парсинг
- Для поиска игр ищу теги `<a>`, у которых в ссылке есть строка `/game/`
- У найденных атрибутов ищу все `div` и те, которые всегда последние и будут содержать название игры

Пример:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = open('https _www.leovegas.com_en-in_popular.html', 'rb').read()
root = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

for x in root.select('a[href*="/game/"]'):
    div = x.select('div')[-1]
    title = div.get_text(strip=True)
    print(title)

    # Hot Spin
    # Reel King Mega
    # ...
    # El Dorado Infinity Reels
    # Rick and Morty MEGAWAYS
```

---

**Второй вариант** возможен из-за того, что данные по играм находятся на странице в куске `javscript`, в переменной `window.__INITIAL_STATE`:

```
window.__INITIAL_STATE = {"query:StructureQuery:{}":{ ...
```

Алгоритм:

- Вытаскиваем этот кусок через регулярное выражение
- Парсим его в `JSON`
- Вытаскиваем игры в удобном формате

Пример:

```
import json
import re
import sys

with open('https _www.leovegas.com_en-in_popular.html', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

m = re.search('window.__INITIAL_STATE = ({.+});', text)
if not m:
    print('Not found "window.__INITIAL_STATE"!')
    sys.exit(1)

data = json.loads(m.group(1))

query = data['query:CasinoCategoryScreenQuery:{invalidPath:false,lobbyId:"TG9iYnk6Y2FzaW5v",slug:"popular",urlPath:"/popular"}']
items = query['data']['category']['games']['edges']
for node in items:
    title = node['node']['name']
    print(title)

# Hot Spin
# Reel King Mega
# LeoVegas MEGAWAYS
# ...
# Volatile Slot
# El Dorado Infinity Reels
# Rick and Morty MEGAWAYS
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, Илья, мне захотелось первым способом сделать, но вот названия игр у меня не печатаются. А на второе решение выдает ошибку:C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3334: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

Comment: Это возможно, если css-селектор `a[href*="/game/"]` ничего не нашел. Но такое будет если структура страницы другая. Скорее всего, то, что вы парсите что-то не то. У меня например, при отключении проверки сертификата в `requests` через параметр `verify=False`, провайдер подсовывал заглушку по поводу заблокированного сайта, тогда тоже не выводило, я об этом в начале ответа написал. А так, вы ведь тестируете код на `LeoVegas.html`? Если сможете предоставить его, я могу посмотреть что там не так

Comment: Насчет второго, очень странная ошибка, впервые такую вижу. Я код запускаю в IDE PyCharm и после вашей ошибки также запустил через консоль `cmd`: `python main.py` и проблем не возникло, скорее всего, это какая-то ошибка интерактивной оболочки

Comment: куда прислать файл?

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, например, на pastebin. Кст, я тот файл из ответа положил, проверьте с ним код: https://pastebin.com/a73GKzJf

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает!

Comment: Добрый день, вот , например, для  данного сайта https://www.royalpanda.com/most-popular/ как будет выглядить регулярное выражение? таким образом: root.select('div [class*="/omg-cas-but-title/"]')  не работает.

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, там у всех тегов с названиями есть определенный класс, поиск такой: `root.select('.omg-cas-but-title')`. Тыкаете правой кнопкой на страницу, выбираете `Исходный код` и смотрите там, так я и нашел на прошлом сайте `window.__INITIAL_STATE`, а на этом скорее всего в: `var games = `, там регулярка аналогичная

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего контент генерируется динамически. Таким способом вы его не получите. Используйте эмулятор браузера. Вот эта библиотека вполне подойдёт: [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)